# MembershipProvider Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to use [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) to write a website, I am quit new to the framework And I am not sure if using `MembershipProvider` Class is a good idea or not.
Or it is better to implement it by myself.

Could you please tell me what are `MembershipProvider` drawbacks? and if I use it would I have control over it.

Comment: *`I want to use Asp.net MVC to write a website`*: I hope you don't expect that on the basis on this information you will get any viable answers as to whether using the `MembershipProvider` class is a good idea or not.

Comment: It is an ecommerce  website which user can login and register and they can buy things from it.They should entere their bank detail.....

Comment: @ Darin: Should I provide more information? could you please tell me what information I should provide?

Comment: [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) is just a base class for (quoting MSDN) "providing membership services". For example, [SqlMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx) is a class that inherits from MembershipProvider, and uses Sql Server to store user names, e-mails etc. Lots of web sites use it. Try going through the [sqlmembershipprovider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlmembershipprovider) tag to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the purpose of your website, using MembershipProvider basically gives you flexibility in providing the control of most basic user account management (like login, forget pwd, register, etc).

By inheriting from MembershipProvider class, you are then are exposed to various methods and properties to support membership system. You still have to write code for the implementation of your choice, of course, but eventually you can use multiple or swap them via web.config.